# Using codecs in program

Tags: c++, windows, qt, codec, multimedia

As I've mentioned in my [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18134724/qmediaplayer-resource-error), I'm having trouble with Qt 5.1's multimedia module. The `QMediaPlayer` class can't play *some* MP3 files. I haven't tested other formats thoroughly.

I'm not sure if this is a codec related problem. But I'm interested in using codec directly in my program rather than relying on the backend support for playing media files. I'll be developing the application in Qt 5.1 for desktop Windows platform.

I have no idea about using codecs in programs. Any pointer will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to [FFMPEG]: http://www.ffmpeg.org/ to integrate the open-source codec to play your media file.