# How to get a list of video containers supported by QMediaPlayer based on underlying system environment?

Tags: qt, audio, video, pyside, codec

I am using the latest PySide2 available from Anaconda using Python 3.7 on Windows 10. My question on the other hand is not restricted to whether PySide, PyQt or Qt C++ is used.

While trying to integrate video playback in a custom `QVideoWidget` that is to be docked in a main window I decided to test using some samples using two popular containers:

- [AVI](https://file-examples.com/index.php/sample-video-files/sample-avi-files-download/)
- [MPEG-4](https://file-examples.com/index.php/sample-video-files/sample-mp4-files/)

The first worked without any issue. The second however lead to the `QMediaPlayer` landing in a `ResourceError` error state. Sadly `errorString()` is empty so I am unable to find the issue.

I know that the player is tightly coupled with the media codecs installed on the target system (Windows, Linux). I would like to know if there is a way to get a list of what the `QMediaPlayer` supports once initialized. This will allow me to disable features in my custom `QVideoWidget` including which files are visible via the `QFileDialog` so prevent the user from trying to load something that simply cannot be loaded. My priority is video (meaning I load every video muted and don't intend to play any audio be it as part of the video or as an audio container) however information on audio should proof to be useful to a more general audience.

Comment: There's no direct nor easy solution for this: QMediaPlayer is fundamentally a wrapper around the system multimedia capabilities, so it all depends on how the system will support the given file. You also have to consider 2 aspects: 1. you cannot completely rely on the file extension to ensure that a media is actually "loadable"; 2. media files are normally composed of a container and a number of streams; this means that even if you get a `.mp4` file, it could actually be another container format, and even if that is supported, it's still possible any of its audio/video streams are not.

Comment: The problem is that the player is actually only *very loosely* coupled with the system codecs. Qt itself does not use those codecs at all, since it hands everything off to the backend. There is [QMediaPlayer.hasSupport](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaplayer.html#hasSupport), which provides an [estimate](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmultimedia.html#SupportEstimate-enum) per mime-type. But no static list as such, since the underlying information is mostly outside Qt's control (and potentially highly volatile).

Comment: The only way to get the supported formats/codecs would be to create your own way of querying the system media backend (which would be very complex and completely different for each OS), and even after that you'll never be 100% sure that the file will be actually read: as said, media files are usually containers of streams, so it's possible that the container is supported and the codec is not (and viceversa) or even that the mix of container/stream is not supported, due to lack of special/unusual feature support, or higher compliancy to format/codec "strictness". You can only open it and hope.

Comment: @musicamante Of course file extension is not what I'm analyzing. As someone who works mostly on Linux I know it has no meaning except a chunk of metadata that helps distinguish it in an easier way from other files and for better integration (e.g. Windows Explorer is very confused if a file has no extension :D).

Comment: How about `ResourceError`? Is there a way to get more information (from Qt) on that? I read an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22621094/1559401) here on SO where the issue (with an audio file) was an old ID3 tag.

Comment: @rbaleksandar then you partially answered your own question: the file has to be opened first to check its mime type (which would *theoretically* provide you a possible compatibility guess with `hasSupport` as ekhumoro points out), but then the file could still not be readable if the backend doesn't support its structure or the video stream, which could only be tested by directly opening the file. The error is only what the backend reports (which is rather generic), other than that you cannot get anything else. You have to remember that QMediaPlayer is a *high* level API, it doesn't provide ->

Comment: @rbaleksandar -> higher "inspection" over the format/stream/codec problems, since, considering its scope, it would be usually be unnecessary: knowing the reason of the error won't help you solve it, since it's relying on an external file.

Comment: @rbaleksandar AVI is a proprietary Microsoft format, so your Windows 10 system has native support for it - but MPEG-4 does not. Regardless of that, you may have some apps that can play mp4 files by bundling in their own support. But Qt doesn't do things that way. It uses a DirectShow backend, which only has built-in support for a limited range of video formats, but can be easily extended by [installing a third-party codec pack](https://codecguide.com/download_kl.htm). So it's pretty much a given on Windows that all users will have to install those extra codecs at some point.

Comment: @rbaleksandar Trying to prevent users loading certain formats is probably the wrong approach. You should instead inform them that they may need to install some extra codecs (and perhaps direct Windows users to a reliable third-party site that can provide them for free). That will very likely fix the large majority of `ResourceError`-type issues on most systems.

Comment: @ekhumoro Informing the users about codecs is also on my list. That said I can only recommend some popular packages based on the system they are on. I actually hoping to use the information that comes from the error reporting of the `QMediaPlayer` to present a more accurate guideline but I guess generic solution is the best I can do. I am also aware that Qt doesn't come with bundled codecs. I was just looking for some hidden function I missed in the documentation. :D

Comment: @rbaleksandar Well, the "hidden" function in Qt5 is `hasSupport`. Did you try it with your MPEG-4 example? I assume you get the `ResourceError` on your system because you haven't installed the extra codecs. In which case, `hasSupport('video/mp4')` should return `QMultimedia.NotSupported`. Of course, if you *have* installed the codecs, some files may still not load properly. But in that case, a putative list of "supported" formats has no diagnostic value, since it would report a false positive.

Comment: @rbaleksandar For Qt6, the situation is completely different, because it has a dedicated [QMediaFormat](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmediaformat.html) class, which provides a much more sophisticated API than Qt5 (including a [supportedVideoCodecs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmediaformat.html#supportedVideoCodecs) method). So I suppose one answer to your question might be: upgrade to PySide6 (assuming, of course, that upgrading is feasible for all your intended users).